# K-means numpy error in image compression

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, k-means

I have been trying to implement k means for image compression using pixels as the data and k as the number of centroids. I keep getting an error of: `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`; in the comparison statement for `if assignment[i] == j:`. I decided to calculate the initial centroid first, then use that to cluster the data points to the correct centroids. Then recalculate the centroid using the assignment variable into argmin.

My code:

```
def mykmeans(pixels, K):
    k=int(K)
    #number of pixels dimension
    pixel_num=pixels.shape[0]
    print('Pixel num',pixel_num)
    pixel_rand1=np.random.randint(pixel_num,size=(1,k))
    int_cent=pixels[pixel_rand1[0],:] #new centroids
    #for initial centroids
    dis_temp1=np.array((pixel_num,k))
    assignment= [None]*pixel_num
    for i in range(pixel_num):
        for j in range(k):
            dis_temp1[j]=linalg.norm(pixels[i]-int_cent[j])**2
    assignment=np.argmin(dis_temp1)
    print('Assignemnt',int(assignment))
    x_new=int_cent
    new_assign=np.array([])
    for i in range(pixel_num):
        for j in range(k):
            if assignment[i] is j:
                new_assign += assignment[i]
    #for after initial centroid
    while (linalg.norm(x_new-x_old) <1e-4):
        #part 1
        for i in range(pixel_num):
            for j in range(k):
                dis_temp[j]=linalg.norm(pixels[i]-x_old[j])**2
        assignment[i]=np.argmin(dis_temp)
        #        
        #        #part 2
        new_assign=[]
        for i in range(pixel_num):
            for j in range(k):
                if assignment[i] == j:
                    new_assign += assignment[i]
            x_new[j]=np.mean(new_assign,axis=0)
            centroid=x_new

    print(assignment)
    print(centroid)
    return assignment, centroid
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `assignment` is a scalar variable.

Therefore, you cannot access `assignment` by an index, so `assignment[i] = j` will give you the error.

`assignment` is set here `assignment=np.argmin(dis_temp1)` where `dist_temp1` is a 1-d array.

When you pass a 1-d array to `np.argmin` it returns a scalar: see the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html).

Initially you set `assignment= [None]*pixel_num`, so you need to be careful of reassigning you variables.

You should also look at how you define `dis_temp`, as the following will produce an error for `k>2`

```
for i in range(pixel_num):
  for j in range(k):
      dis_temp1[j]=linalg.norm(pixels[i]-int_cent[j])**2
```

Perhaps you meant to define `dis_temp1 = np.zeros((pixel_num,k))` and the loop as

```
for i in range(pixel_num):
  for j in range(k):
      dis_temp1[i][j]=linalg.norm(pixels[i]-int_cent[j])**2
  assignment[i]=np.argmin(dis_temp1)
```

This moves the code forward to a new error where `x_old` has not been defined.